# Как Symfony узнает, какой ObjectManager нужно создать

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

Вопрос возможно странный, но все же.
Имеем конфиг из [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) Symfony 4:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            customer:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    Customer:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                        alias: Customer
```

здесь два менеджера customer и default.
Далее документация говорит, хотите юзать, используйте:

```php
// ...

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        // These methods also return the default entity manager, but it's preferred
        // to get it by injecting EntityManagerInterface in the action method
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
        $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

        // Both of these return the "customer" entity manager
        $customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer');
        $customerEntityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.customer_entity_manager');
    }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем, как Symfony знает, экземпляр какого класса(т.е. какой Manager) необходимо передать аргументом в метод индекс? В конфиге указано, что дефолтный, но нигде нет сопоставления имени default с конкретным Manager-ом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доктрина создает несколько экземпляров одного класса менеджера и кладет их в реестр под именами из конфига. Механизм приведен в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1030349/210020

Внутри реестра это массив, ключами которого являются имена менеджеров, а значениями - объекты менеджеров. Это, собственно, и есть сопоставление

PS: `$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');` - лучше не делать
правильнее

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

PPS: И работать с доктринячьими потрохами лучше не в контроллерах, а в сервисах

Answer (score 1):

как нет? а здесь: /vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php

```php
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function getManager($name = null)
    {
        if ($name === null) {
            $name = $this->defaultManager;
        }

        if (! isset($this->managers[$name])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Doctrine %s Manager named "%s" does not exist.', $this->name, $name));
        }

        return $this->getService($this->managers[$name]);
    }
```

или я что-то не правильно понял?

Comment: Я запутался немного в этой горе кода)
Кажется начал понимать)
Я правильно понимаю, что строка в конфиге "entity_managers:" однозначно говорит, что все нижеуказанные менеджеры это экземпляры Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager?

Comment: я думал, что: default => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, а customer => это какой-нибудь Custom\dir\CustomManager

Comment: не могу сказать наверняка. для меня это тоже пока гора кода. однако, все менеджеры конечно должны по меньшей мере наследовать единый интерфейс

Comment: все правильно. создается несколько именованных экземпляров одного менеджера (каждый со своим соединением) и отдаются доктриной по имени

Comment: @abu спасибо, можно в ответ)